# how to update nested array of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, object, mongoose, nested, updating

Here is my db collection in mongoDB. I am using mongoose to update the data inside the comments array

```
{
        "author": {
            "email": "user@example.com",
            "userName": "John"
        },
        "_id": "63bc20741475b40323d6259f",
        "title": "this is blog",
        "description": "description",
        "blogBanner": "https://github.com//routers/userRouter.js",
        "views": "0",
        "comments": [
            {
                "userId": "63b919840ae5303938fb1c17",
                "comment": "first comment",
                "_id": "_id:63bbdbdb7018eabb752c0e58
            },
            {
                "userId": "63b919840ae5303938fb1c17",
                "comment": "second comment",
                "_id": "63bbdbdb7018eabb752ce55"
            }
        ],
        "reaction": [
            {
                "userEmail": "gias@gmail.com",
                "react": "love"
            }
        ],
        "date": "2023-01-09T14:09:32.810Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

here i want to update  the first comment by using `comment._id: 63bbdbdb7018eabb752c0e58`

how can i update the single comment by using `comment._id` ;

use-case : when user want to update his/her comment by using `comment._id`

here i want to update  the first comment by using `comment._id: 63bbdbdb7018eabb752c0e58`

how can i update the single comment by using `comment._id`;

use-case : when user want to update his/her comment by using `comment._id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, read the following docs:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array

```
Model.update(
 {  
 '_id': '63bc20741475b40323d6259f',
 'comments._id':'63bbdbdb7018eabb752ce55' 
},
  { $set: { "comments.$.comment" : 'Edited Text' } }
)
```